# Testing if the initialization of static local objects is thread-safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, initialization

I'm trying to write a test (without examining the assembly code) to see whether a certain compiler is conformant with the thread-safe requirement of the c++11 standard about the initialization of static local objects.

So far I can only come up with non-deterministic approaches (sleeping for a long enough time on one thread to make it likely (but not surely, problem!) that the other thread has run to a certain point of execution).

Is there a way to do it deterministically?

Comment: No. See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196105/testing-multi-threaded-race-conditions

Comment: You want to test with objects of arbitrary type, e.g. pods, I suppose. Because otherwise you could try some sync voodoo in a custom ctor.

Comment: @Solkar Would you elaborate about "sync voodoo" please? I can use a custom ctor.

Comment: @Mankarse If you could point me to the MSVC12, GCC4.9, clang3.5 menus regarding this, please do.

Comment: @nos Interesting read, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. a *sync voodoo* (see comments) like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex g_mutex;

const std::chrono::seconds g_dura(1);

void log(const char* msg) {
    std::clog << std::this_thread::get_id() 
              << " "  << msg 
              << std::endl;
}

struct Asset {
    Asset () {
        log("before lock attempt");
        g_mutex.lock();
        log("after lock attempt");
        /*EDIT*/g_mutex.unlock();
    }
};

void test() {
    log("entering test()");
    static Asset asset; 
    log("leaving test()");
}

int main() {
    g_mutex.lock();
    std::thread t1(test), t2(test);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(g_dura);

    // cleanup
    g_mutex.unlock();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

This lets the first thread (not necessarily t1), which has to do the init, wait in the ctor, and desired behaviour is, that the second (not necessarily t1) thread waits **before** the pending static variable init (in the first thread) is completed.

So there is just **one** pair of "before lock attempt"/"after lock attempt" messages printed if the compiler works correctly.

g++ (Debian 4.8.2-16) behaved well.

That *voodoo* can be put to the top if the t1,t2 themselves manage the control flow of the main thread; I skipped that and simply set a timer.

Comment: Not sure this is reliable. It gives the 'correct' output (ie. a single pair of lock attempt messages) on MSVC11, which does _not_ implement magic statics.

Comment: also just one "before lock attempt" message? I originally forgot to unlock the mutex (set at /*EDIT*/).

Comment: Yes. I get `t1 - entering`, `t1 - before attempt`, `t2 - entering`, `t2 - leaving`, `t1 - after attempt`, `t1 - leaving`. Seems the second thread executes the function even though the object is not yet fully constructed.

Comment: Good point. Let's try to actually **use** that object in addition! Could well be that msvc just optimizes that 2nd call away.

Comment: I was just wondering : why you used `std::clog`? (instead of `std::cout` or `std::cerr`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I don't think it is deterministic. Let's say we are using a compiler that is not standard-conforming in this regard. t2 could stall (for whatever reason) for more than a second before running, thus allowing t1 to complete the initialization (printing one pair of "before lock attempt"/"after lock attempt" messages). This would produce a false positive that the compiler is standard-conforming.

Comment: So the sine qua non for determinism appears to be having means for diagnosing whether the 2nd threat is actually waiting for the init to complete or for "sth" else before we unlock the first. (the mutex unlock itself could be refined; there are more sophisticated means than a plain timer, as I already indicated).

Comment: Yes, but how? I've searched for a way to query whether a thread is in a waiting state on windows and on linux, but couldn't find it.

Comment: I commented out in main() the sleep() and unlock(), so that all three threads were wainting and had a look with gdb. main() is at pthread_join (imagine that.. ;)), the 1st worker thread is, in the ctor at  __lll_lock_wait() in [..]unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135, and the 2nd worker thread right where it should, thus before the static in syscall() at [...]unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S:38. I'll look at the Linux side tmrw, it's 90 to soccer time now ;). cu

Comment: I understand that would require some intimate knowledge of the linux kernel, at least more intimate than mine currently; my last time in the kernel is about a decade ago. Maybe best you rephrase that certain issue to a system programming topic and open another, more specific question.